# Weird Installation

Tags: android, installation

I have made two application, both having two different classes and xml files and all. however, after i have installed the first application (lets call it A) and after that, i want to install the second application (B), there is a pop up message stating "android do you want to install an update to this existing application? your existing data will not be lost. it does not require any special access."
when i press ok, A will be gone from my phone and will be replaced with B. why does this occur? can anyone help me so i can install both my apps without either one disappearing ?

Comment: check in the manifest of both the apps. you probably have the same package name for both apps.

Comment: do i have to rename the subpackages? or only just change the package name?

Comment: open the manifest, look for the package attribute and change its value.

Comment: upvotes for the comment?

Comment: sorry. i didnt know u could do that for comment. ok done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Right click on your project, go to Android Tools, and then click on Rename Application Package**.

If it is not working then follow these steps

```
1. Right-click on your project package name
2. Refactor > Rename.
3. change the package name in the manifest file. Inside the <manifest> tag. 
4. Open each of tyour Activity files and add missing import packages (Ctrl-Shift-O)
```

Answer (score 3):

The manifests of both applications have the same package name in it. That's why you get the replace notification. Change the packagename of the 2 apps.

Comment: do i have to rename the subpackages? or only just change the package name?

Comment: Package name in your manifest, not the packages of the classes